# Why is my Samsung Galaxy S not utilizing all of its RAM?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my device not utilizing all of its available RAM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22373/why-is-my-device-not-utilizing-all-of-its-available-ram)

Samsung Galaxy S GT I9000 comes with 512 MB RAM but it shows only 326 or less. Why?

Comment: Install `Terminal Emulator` from Market and run `free -m` command. What does it say?

Comment: Just noticed i gave wrong instructions to check RAM usage previously. I use **Quick System Info PRO** found on Google Play to check free RAM. On *"Basic Info"* tab you should see that and if you want additional details,  just navigate to *"Memory"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrong.

Galaxy S does have 512 Mb. the problem is that you cannot use it all for programs.
From that 512 Mb of memory 128 Mb are reserved for graphical purposes and for phone modem.
You don't want any call to end because programs running took all that memory, do you?

The problem with the Galaxy S is that if we take into account that 128Mb we should have 384.
But for some reason it display 326 and 304 in some cases. That black hole is the mistery.

Still I could not find anyone that explains that to me.

Hope this eases your soul. You have 512 Mb. They just did not told you that you could not use it all. ;)

Comment: some source says that android 2.1 does not support 512 mb RAM thats why it shows less and 2.2 support 512 mb RAM. Is it true ?