# How to active the RAM memory which is differents with 512 MB when buying

Tags: ram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my device not utilizing all of its available RAM?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22373/why-is-my-device-not-utilizing-all-of-its-available-ram)

I have new problem with my Novo 7 Basic, Android 3.2, 8GB, 512 MB** RAM:

When I go into `Tools -> System Info` (have CPU, Display, Memory...) in Memory Info:

- Total Mem 343.MB + Free Mem   36.048 MB (<512 MB RAM)
- Inactive     94.496 MB

When I used : "Android Assitant app ", it shows my Memory info (RAM) is:

- Used : 183,96MB
- Free:  150,95MB

Total: 334.96 MB

"RAM Manager Free software ", it says that Memory info is:

- MemTotal: 343.000 MB & MemFree: 7012 kB

But my tablet is supposed to have 512 MB of RAM. Please explain this to me (for any problems or errors). How do I activate the "inactive mem 94.496 MB"?

Answer (score 3):

This memory is not inactive. It is reserved for the GPU and the radios (wi-fi, bluetooth etc.)

You cannot activate it because it's already in use.