# RAM of HTC one (m7)?

Tags: ram, htc-one

From the technical details it seems that HTC one (m7) has 2Gb of RAM, but if I check the RAM usage the smartphone shows that I am using around 900 Mb of 1.5Gb. There is something that I do not understand?

Comment: Also [Why is my device not utilizing all of its available RAM?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22373/why-is-my-device-not-utilizing-all-of-its-available-ram)