# How to check if my phone components are what they should be (is Dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9 equal to ARMv7 Processor rev 3)?

Tags: hardware, manufacturers

I've bought LG Optimus L9 P760 - it came to me from China, without the foil and with unpacked charger. There was also no guarantee included (and I was assured there will be 24-moths written one). That's why I decided to check carefully everything else too.

It should have those parameters, [according to specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_l9_p760-4955.php):

```
Chipset              TI OMAP 4430
CPU                  Dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9
GPU                  PowerVR SGX540
```

But when I've installed the *Android System Info* application and exterminated the *CPU*:

```
Proccessor:          ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
processor            0
BogoMIPS             1592.38
processor            1
BogoMIPS             1592.38
CPU implementer      0x41
CPU architecture     7
CPU variant          0x1
CPU part             0xc09
CPU revision         3
Hardware             LGE P760 board
Revision             0007
Serial               000000000000000
Frequency range:     300.0 -> 1008.0MHz
Current Frequency:   800HMz
```

**Is that the right CPU?** Because I see **ARMv7 Processor rev 3** instead of **TI OMAP 4430** - but maybe those are 2 different things or some alias? **Or maybe I've been ripped off by the seller?** Is that possible?

System Info Droid also listed *ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)* and I cannot find Dual-core 1 GHz Cortex-A9* anywhere (however, I see that it's dual processor).

Also, under *Memory*:

```
Download Cache Max:     194MB
data Max:               2.33GB
External storage Max:   2.33GB
Total RAM:              767MB
Threshold RAM:          64.00MB
```

I see **767MB RAM**, where there should be **1GB RAM**. Is there something wrong, or some amount of RAM is not listed somehow?

Comment: Try this . SysHard Info - show system and hardware information on Android
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kinocat.andinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A9_MPCore),

> The ARM Cortex-A9 MPCore is a 32-bit multicore processor providing up to 4 cache-coherent Cortex-A9 cores, **each implementing the ARM v7 instruction set architecture**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

Also, from the same article,

> ## Chips
>
> Several system on a chip (SoC) devices implement the Cortex-A9 core, including:
>
> - ...
> - Texas Instruments OMAP4 processors ([TI OMAP 4430](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/wtbu/wtbuproductcontent.tsp?contentId=53243&navigationId=12843&templateId=6123))
> - ...

And with help from [eldarerathis's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91534/how-to-check-if-my-phone-components-are-what-they-should-be-is-dual-core-1-ghz#comment114828_91534)

> The RAM difference is because apps will only report RAM that is [available to userspace processes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22373/why-is-my-device-not-utilizing-all-of-its-available-ram/22385#22385).

(the detail can be read on that post)